# Dovecot service stopped

Tags: 10.10, services, dovecot

I am running on  Ubuntu 10.10.
My Problem is; dovecot service automatically stops. How to get rid of this problem?

Here is the line from the dovecot log.

```
dovecot: dovecot: Fatal: Time just moved backwards by 17 seconds. This might cause a lot of problems, so I'll just kill myself now. http://wiki.dovecot.org/TimeMovedBackwards: 1 Time(s)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is ntpd running?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your system clock moving backwards during operation, that is what you need to fix. There are other applications which will not work properly if the system time is moved  backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the log indicates - you're going to want to have a look at [Dovecot Wiki: Time Moved Backwards](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/TimeMovedBackwards) The article details that this is due to ntpdate running and updating the time in chunks too big for Dovecot to handle. It also lists several alternatives - primarily running `ntpd` which will simply slow or speed the clock up and not preform a hard reset.

It also provides methods for disabling this check in Dovecot itself.